# Is bootstrap.js specifically a library or a plugin or something else?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, frameworks

Is bootstrap.js specifically a library or a plugin or can be classified as something else?

Comment: It's a CSS framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS or Front-end framework ;-)

"Bootstrap is a free and open-source collection of tools for creating websites and web applications. It contains HTML- and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. As of March 2015, it was the most-starred project on GitHub, with over 78,000 stars and more than 30,000 forks.[2]"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)

Difference between API's, Plug-In and Framework : 
http://collap.com/challengesOpen.php?challenge_id=715

Comment: "Bootstrap is a free and open-source collection of tools for creating websites and web applications." then it's a library, not a framework.